# jQuery UI wrong results on inline

Tags: jquery-ui, progress-bar

I'm trying to create progress bar with text before it, like this:

```
Progress: [======>     ]
```

but whenever I'm inserting  tag with style "display: inline;" after text, jQuery UI progress bar shows wrong results.

Can anyone suggest me how to do it right? Thank you.

However, jsFiddle doesn't show that 'wrong result'. Using Firefox on Linux.

http://jsfiddle.net/gEmsp/

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this:

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/gEmsp/1/][1]
```

Wrap label text in container.

Comment: Thank you! Worked as expected.